# Convert byte array to integer array on the fly

Tags: javascript, arrays

from a webserver I receive a large byte array that is composed of N integers (signed 16 bit, little endian) and I want to build an array of integers in javascript.

Of course I could just iterate over the incoming array and push in each couple of bytes. There's no problem doing this.

I'm wondering if there is a more convenient way to fill the array. For example, in C, I may set an integer pointer to the first byte and then access to all the others. Or better I can malloc and memcpy the buffer area to a reserved space. In both cases I don't have to iterate the source array.

Comment: Surely in JavaScript it's expressed as an array of Number anyhow?

Comment: What exactly does the incoming array look like when you `console.log()` it?

Comment: You need to iterate over the array anyway, no convenient way.

Comment: Does this have to work on older browsers? If not, you can used Typed Arrays.

Comment: @Cerbrus: in console I see the ascii symbols.

Comment: @int3: no need to older browsers compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer browsers that support Typed Arrays, you can make an XHR request with the `responseType` request parameter [set to `"arraybuffer"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Receiving_binary_data_using_JavaScript_typed_arrays). The response will then be an `ArrayBuffer` object, which you can pass to a [`Int32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Int32Array?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript_typed_arrays%2FInt32Array) constructor.

Comment: Interesting. I'll investigate further if the webserver is capable of handle the request. It's a small PIC based server.

Answer (score 1):

This will convert two bytes (8 bits each) into an Integer

```
function Two8bitBytestoOneInteger(byteHighBits,byteLowBits){
   return  ( byteHighBits.charCodeAt(0) << 8 ) | ( byteLowBits.charCodeAt(0) & 0xFF ) ;
}
```

*Hint:*
if you try to print bytes (i.e. `console.log(byteHighBits)`) you get an error `NaN` (not a number) so to see the byte integer value do this `(  console.log(byteHighBits.charCodeAt(0)   )`

Hope this helps!